# finding variance from a piecewise function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

How do you calculate the variance of a piecewise function? For example, what would be the variance of the probability density function $f_x(x)= \frac{3}{4}, 0\leq x\leq 1; \frac{1}{4}, 2\leq x \leq 3; 0$ otherwise?

Comment: The ordinary way, you integrate, find say $\int_0^3 x^2f(x)\,dx$, subtract the square of $\int_0^3 xf(x)\,dx$.  Now when you are *doing* the integrations, you have to break them up, $0$ to $1$, and $2$ to $3$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $U$ be a [continuous uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) random variable on a unit interval. It's mean and variance are 
$$\mathbb{E}(U) = \frac{1}{2} \qquad \qquad
   \mathbb{Var}(U) = \mathbb{E}(U^2) - \left(\mathbb{E}(U)\right)^2 = \frac{1}{12}
$$
Now, your continuous random variable $X$ is a [component mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of a uniform $U$ and shifted uniform $2+U$ with weights $w_1 = \frac{3}{4}$ and $w_2 = \frac{1}{4}$.

Then
$$
   \mathbb{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \left(\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2 = 
     \left( w_1 \mathbb{E}(U^2) + w_2 \mathbb{E}((2+U)^2) \right) - \left( w_1 \mathbb{E}(U) + w_2 \mathbb{E}(2+U) \right)^2
$$ 
Since $\mathbb{E}(U^2) = \mathbb{Var}(U) + \left(\mathbb{E}(U)\right)^2 = \frac{1}{3}$, $\mathbb{E}((2+U)^2) = 4 + 4 \mathbb{E}(U) + \mathbb{E}(U^2) = \frac{19}{3}$. Therefore
$$
   \mathbb{Var}(X) = \left( \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{19}{3} \right) - \left( \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{5}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{11}{6} - 1^2 = \frac{5}{6}
$$